# importing pycurl with libcurl4 raises ImportError

Tags: python, pip, libcurl, pycurl, pipenv

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. If I install libcurl4 (instead of libcurl3), when I import pycurl installed with pipenv I get

```
>>> import pycurl
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by /home/pietro/envs/try_fabric-kcbGLH3z/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycurl.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

Note that this error is raised only when I use a pycurl installed with pipenv or pip. If I use instead pycurl installed through apt on system python there are any errors...

What can I do to avoid this impasse?

Comment: `rm - rf ~/.cache/pip` and try again? I assume you upgraded your os recently?

Comment: wonder... It is right and it works (remembering also to reload the environment `source ~/.zshrc` in my case). Please, write the full answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you upgraded your operating system recently.

pip stores a cache of built wheels in your home directory, when upgrading your os it is a good idea to clear this cache as the binaries may now link against incompatible system libraries

You can do this by `rm -rf ~/.cache/pip` and then recreate your environment